# How to correctly handle Hikari connection pool in SpringBoot and oracle with java?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a service that does 10 parallel tasks and when all of them finish, it returns a response.
In my opinion, I can implement it in 2 ways—the first one is creating in a usual way, and the second one is using the multi-thread concept.
I coded and compared both. But I had been having a problem with the connection pool in multithreaded.

When I send specific requests at a particular time (e.g. 1000 requests per 0.001 seconds) with JMeter in the usual implementation, all requests are done; but while running it with the multithread implement, some of the requests are failed.
The cause of this problem is related to the connection pool; Service is gotten the Hikari pool error.

I know one solution as increment the Hikari pool, but I can't do it, because the speed of the oracle database will decrease (I don't have access to it).
What is the best practice for handling multi-threads in this situation? increasing Hikari pool or dividing threads into smaller parts?

( Technologies used:Springboot v2.6.0, Java 14, Oracle database, for multithread used  completeableFuture from java.util.concurrent, JMeter (last version) )

The code shows you, all my configurations in the application.properties :

```
#maximum number of milliseconds that a client will wait for a connection
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 20000

#minimum number of idle connections maintained by HikariCP in a connection pool
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10000

#maximum pool size
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 10000

#maximum idle time for connection
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000

# maximum lifetime in milliseconds of a connection in the pool after it is closed.
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000
```

Implementation of multithreaded :

```
@Override
    public AllInquiriesDTO getAllInquiries(Long cardRequestId, String outputPostCode, String outputTraceId) {

        AllInquiriesDTO allInquiriesDTO = new AllInquiriesDTO();
        CompletableFuture<Void> gomrokHoghooghiInquiry = this.getGomrokHoghooghiInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setGomrokHoghoghi);
        CompletableFuture<Void> returnCheckInquiry = this.getReturnCheckInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setReturnCheck);
        CompletableFuture<Void> behinyabInquiry = this.getBehinyabInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setBehinyab);
        CompletableFuture<Void> graduationInquiry = this.getGraduationInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setGraduation);
        CompletableFuture<Void> legalPersonalInfoInquiry = this.getLegalPersonalInfoInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setLegalPersonalInfo);
        CompletableFuture<Void> tax186TaeedInquiry = this.getTax186TaeedInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setTax186Taeed);
        CompletableFuture<Void> tax186SodoorInquiry = this.getTax186SodoorInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setTax186Sodoor);
        CompletableFuture<Void> taxAnnualDetailListInquiry = this.getTaxAnnualDetailListInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(res -> allInquiriesDTO.getTax186Sodoor().get(0).setTaxAnnualDetailList(res));
        CompletableFuture<Void> postInquiry = this.getPostInquiry(cardRequestId).
                thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setPost);
        CompletableFuture<Void> gomrokHaghighiInquiry = this.getGomrokHaghighiInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setGomrokHaghighi);
        CompletableFuture<Void> nezamVazifeInquiry = this.getNezamVazifeInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setNezamVazife);
        CompletableFuture<Void> sahaInquiry = this.getSahaInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setSaha);
        CompletableFuture<Void> amlakInquiry = this.getAmlakInquiry(cardRequestId, outputPostCode, outputTraceId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setAmlak);
        CompletableFuture<Void> jahadInquiry = this.getJahadInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setJahad);
        CompletableFuture<Void> employeeCheckInquiry = this.getEmployeeCheckInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setEmployeeCheck);
        CompletableFuture<Void> taeminDebtInquiry = this.getTaeminDebtInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setTaminDebt);
        CompletableFuture<Void> madanInquiry = this.getMadanInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setMadan);
        CompletableFuture<Void> cCompanyInquiry = this.getCCompanyInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setCCompany);
        CompletableFuture<Void> soePishineInquiry = this.getSoePishineInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setSoePishine);
        CompletableFuture<Void> managerInfoInquiry = this.getManagerInfoInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setManagerInfo);
        CompletableFuture<Void> tanzimMoghararatInquiry = this.getTanzimMoghararatInquiry(cardRequestId)
                .thenAccept(allInquiriesDTO::setTanzimMoghararat);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(gomrokHoghooghiInquiry, returnCheckInquiry, behinyabInquiry, graduationInquiry,
                legalPersonalInfoInquiry, tax186TaeedInquiry,
                tax186SodoorInquiry, taxAnnualDetailListInquiry, postInquiry, gomrokHaghighiInquiry,
                nezamVazifeInquiry, sahaInquiry, amlakInquiry, jahadInquiry, employeeCheckInquiry,
                taeminDebtInquiry, madanInquiry, cCompanyInquiry, soePishineInquiry, managerInfoInquiry,
                tanzimMoghararatInquiry).join();

        return allInquiriesDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<ReturnCheckDTO>> getReturnCheckInquiry(Long cardRequestId) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
                -> returnCheckRepository.findByCardRequestId(cardRequestId));
    }


    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<GraduationDTO>> getGraduationInquiry(Long cardRequestId) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
                -> graduationRepository.findByCardRequestId(cardRequestId));
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<LegalPersonalInfoDTO>> getLegalPersonalInfoInquiry(Long cardRequestId) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
                -> legalPersonalInfoMIMTWSRepository.findByCardRequestId(cardRequestId));
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<Tax186WebServiceTaeed>> getTax186TaeedInquiry(Long cardRequestId) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
                -> tax186DebtRepository.findByCardRequestId(cardRequestId));
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that uses multithreading to access the database

Comment: I would say if your requests are all going to Oracle db better have them implemented in a sequential manner and wrap them in a single transaction (using @Transactional). These all seems to be read queries, so you can mark the transaction as "readOnly" to speed up things a bit (that is if you are using ORM/Hibernate). The fact that you have 10 things going on in parallel shows a design problem. Are these 10 things related? if yes you should explore DB views where you aggregate the data in the DB and fetch with single Inquiry, thus using 1 connection from the pool. maxPoolSize of 10K is bad.